# iPhone - UIWebView - Clicking on a URL before page has loaded makes didFailLoadWithError throw an error

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

In my iPhone application, I'm showing a web page in webview.
I implemented the delegate method as follows:

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Error loading the requested URL" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

When ever I open a URL and loaded half page, i'm immediately clicking some other link in the web page. At that time also, this delegate method is being called.
How should I prevent to call delegate method when web page is loaded half and URL link is clicked.

Or some other solution can be to call stopLoading when some URL is clicked. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I prevent to call delegate method when web page is loaded half and URL link is clicked.

You can't really stop the method from being called - but you might be able to check the properties of the `error` object to determine what kind of error you got.

> Or some other solution can be to call stopLoading when some URL is clicked. How can I do that?

You can use `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` which will be called whenever the user takes some kind of navigation action (e.g. clicks a link, submits a form etc. You can use `navigationType` to determine what the action was). It should be possible to call `stopLoading` from there (though the webView might still call the `webView:didFailWithError:` method, I'm not sure... see the first part on how you can deal with that).

Answer (score 4):

The error code **NSURLErrorCancelled** notifies you that the URLLoadingSystem 'stopped the load'. This happens for instance when the user clicks a link in a page that is only half loaded...the URLLoadingSystem stops it so you don't need to.

```
- (void) webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error 
{   
    // If the URLLoadingSystem cancelled the load don't show anything. 
    if ( [error code] == NSURLErrorCancelled ) 
    {
        //...this is called when the load is cancelled...
    }
    else 
    {
        //...handle the error and show the alert ...
    }
}
```